# Node.js/Express routes redirection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, routes

Having this code in my server.js back-end (Node/Express):

```
  if (isDevelopment()) {
    app.use('/r/', (req, res) => res.redirect('http://localhost:3000' + req.originalUrl));
  }
```

the problem is that when the url ends with `/r` it redirects to a wrong page. I want to make it redirect to `/home`.

So I did it like:

```
  if (isDevelopment()) {
    app.use('/r/', (req, res) => {
      if (!req.originalUrl.endsWith('/')) {
        res.redirect(302, '/home');
      } else {
        res.redirect(302, 'http://localhost:3000' + req.originalUrl);
      }
    });

    app.use('/r', (req, res) => {
      res.redirect(302, '/home');
    });
  }
```

My question is, is the order important here? I want to enter on `app.use('/r/'` when url contains `/r/` but to enter on `app.use('/r'` when it has only `/r`.

Unfortunately I cannot test it locally